# How to reset all properties to their default values in a custom made User Interface Panel

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

I have created a UI Panel with some properties of type IntProperty().

```
bpy.types.Scene.myint = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="My Int Prop", default=9)
```

How can I reset this value to default value '9' on each run script. So, when I change this value in UI Panel to some other value (let's say 10, for example). It remains a changed value (i.e. 10), if I re run the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return a property to its default value,  use [`property_unset(propname)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=property_unset#bpy.types.bpy_struct.property_unset)

Python console code

```
>>> bpy.types.Scene.x = bpy.props.IntProperty(default=3)
>>> C.scene.x
3

>>> C.scene.x = 4
>>> C.scene.x
4

>>> C.scene.property_unset(
property_unset(property)
.. method:: property_unset(property)
Unset a property, will use default value afterward.
>>> C.scene.property_unset("x")
>>> C.scene.x
3
```