# Python: How can I reset a scene property on startup?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I have an addon with several operators. There is one operator that needs to be pressed first before other operators are displayed.  This is the general idea of what I have:

```
context.types.Scene.my_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
     default = False
)

class FirstButtonOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
     def execute(self, context):
          context.scene.my_bool = True
          #do other random stuff here

class SecondButtonOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
     def execute(self, context):
          #do random stuff here

class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
     def draw(self, context):
          layout = self.layout
          if not context.scene.my_Bool:
               #draw first operator
          else:
               #draw second operator
```

Every time blender is opened, I want the second button to be displayed only after the first button is pressed. The code works the first time I run it.  However, when I save the blender file, my_bool is saved as True. Hence, the next time I open blender, the second operator displays instead of the first one.

Is there a way I can reset my_bool to False every time blender is opened?  If not, are there other ways I can accomplish my goal?  I'm new to blender, so I'm not sure if I'm doing things in the optimal way.

Comment: Rather than reset the prop at start, you could reset it at exit : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48566/86891

Comment: Multiple ways to do that (depending on your logic). The easiest is to add `'SKIP_SAVE'` option to your property: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/94035/31447 or calling `property_unset()`: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72852/31447 Also, I recommend take the tour to learn about how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour